# figure positioning according to space available on page

Tags: floats, margins, tufte

I am using Tufte style with symmetric option. I want to force figure automatically to next page if the current page doesn't have enough space to fit the figure at the desired position. Although it automatically goes to next page but than symmetry of page is disturbed.
I found a solution that uses `\needspace{5\baselineskip}` in the redefined figure environment to check for the availability of 5 baselines. I added the following code in tufte-common.def file:

```
\let\oldfigure\figure
\let\oldendfigure\endfigure
\def\figure{\needspace{5\baselineskip}
\begingroup \oldfigure}
\def\endfigure{\centering \oldendfigure \endgroup}
```

and works fine but on the previous page it adds the white space. Instead of white space I want to add the text that followed after the figure. How can I modify this environment according to my requirement.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,symmetric, justified,marginals=justified]{tufte-book} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    
\chapter{MWE} \lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ex­am­ple-im­age-4x3.eps}
\caption{Caption} \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section{MWE-MWE} \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: we haven't got the figure to reproduce the effect (you could edit the example to use `\rule{3cm}{2cm}` or whatever size works to show the problem. The behaviour that you ask for of figures moving to avoid white space is exactly the default behaviour before you redefined it with needspace which will insert a forced page break leaving a page short, it should never be used with a floating figure as the figure may move from that position.

Comment: ...use figures (and dimensions) from [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe). You don't have to include the package manually... just use `example-image`...

Comment: @David and Werner I have updated the mwe with "ex­am­ple-im­age-4x3.eps". David: can you please suggest an efficient solution instead of using needspace, so that the image appears on next page while respecting the symmetry of the new page?

Answer (score 1):

If I do not edit

```
 tufte-common.def
```

To add the use of `\needspace` (which by design adds `\clearpage` and forces the page short) then the figure floats to allow a good page break and all the text appears on page 1,

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the normal behavior but as I mentioned in my main question that I am using the symmetric option due to which if picture goes to next page, it does not respect the symmetry of new page.

Comment: while drafting I can manually place the figure within text but the position of all figures I will be needed to change again manually, if every time I edit my document. It is a big document and containing a lot of figures so I am looking for an adaptive solution to this problem.